# Does using the Stargate make you younger?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-universe

As we have seen from the show *Stargate SG1*, traveling through the Stargate is not instantaneous. It takes a few seconds for a persons (or any items) energy signature to travel from one Stargate to another, yet the person traveling through has the experience of arriving instantly with no time delay.

So does each trip you take through the Stargate technically make you younger (then someone born on earth at the exact same time as you that has never travelled through a Stargate)?

Could it be used as some sort of stasis device?

> We have seen one of our characters get stuck in the Stargate for ~50 hours before

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### The answer isn't necessarily a binary one. Relativistically speaking, if we were tracking the seconds two people had physically existed (let's say a pair of twins) and then one person started using the gate to travel great distances, the time they would "lose" in transit, could begin to add up.

- No, the traveling twin wouldn't be getting younger, they would still be getting older, just a tiny bit slower than their twin who didn't use a stargate regularly (and thought scattering their atoms across the universe a damn-fool way to travel).
- This is a few seconds here, and a few seconds there. It would take quite a significant number of trips for our twins to experience a noticeable difference in their overall aging.
- Now artificially buffering, within the stargate, a person for an extended period could act as a stasis device and while they were buffered, they would be exempt from the aging process, since they technically don't have a body to age. Still wouldn't be getting younger, but they wouldn't technically be getting any older until their body was reconstituted.

Answer (score 10):

In principle you could certainly use the gate as a **storage or stasis device**, converting people into matter and then reintegrating them at a later date.

I don't see any reason why that should result in them becoming 'younger'.

---

The stargate basically works by converting matter into its constituent atoms, sending them via a wormhole to another location and then re-converting them into conventional matter.

In the episode "[48 Hours](http://www.gateworld.net/sg1/s5/514.shtml)" we see Tealc trapped inside the gate itself until they can create a fake wormhole horizon and basically trick the gate into reintegrating him.

Carter explains the principle quite nicely;

> CARTER : You know how the Stargate turns matter into energy and then
>   transmits it through a subspace wormhole?
>
> DANIEL : That's gate travel 101.
>
> CARTER : And the gate on the receiving end is what translates the
>   energy signature and reconverts it back into its original form.
>
> HAMMOND : Major!
>
> CARTER : The Stargate has massive amounts of memory inside it. It's
>   like a computer buffer. It temporarily restores the energy patterns
>   before it reconverts them into matter. Now it does this to make sure
>   it has all the information before it reassembles the object - or in
>   our case, person.The error we're receiving from the gate seems to
>   indicate there's still an energy pattern stored in the memory buffer.
>
> DANIEL : Teal'c?
>
> CARTER : If the Alkesh crashed into the DHD on the other planet it
>   would have cut off power to the outgoing gate. Then the wormhole would
>   have been severed prematurely. Now if that happened before our gate
>   was able to reconvert Teal'c's energy signature back into matter...
>
> HAMMOND : Teal'c is in our Stargate?
>
> CARTER : His energy signature, yes. Stored in the memory.

Rodney and the SG: Atlantis team use the same principle in the episode "[38 Minutes](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Thirty-Eight_Minutes)" where they do this to Sheppard intentionally. He's heavily wounded and it means that from his perspective, he'll get medical attention immediately

[image: 38 minutes]

Travellers don't seem to experience any relativity effects while moving inside the wormhole itself (which is actually pretty consistent with the [Einstein/Rosen](http://www.pbs.org/wnet/hawking/strange/html/wormhole.html) concept of a "bridge" or "gate" between fixed locations in space and time) so the essence is that you don't get younger by travelling in a wormhole, you simply pop in one place and pop out the other. You might appear **not to have aged** but **they don't make time go backwards**.

Comment: In that episode, all of the characters experience over 48 hours more time then Teal'c. Didn't the other characters in the episode experience that time while Teal'c did not? That episode is an exaggeration of what happens normally. In other episodes we see them track a probe as it goes through. They experience a few seconds while the probe does not. How is someone not older/younger at some point?

Comment: This is a good answer, but I suggest editing it to make it more obvious that the 'Gate doesn't so much "make people younger" as it temporarily prevents them from aging. The effects can probably be compared to stasis, but, as you said, stasis doesn't actually make people younger. You need chronotons and Professor Farnsworth for that.

Comment: The other relevant episode is "38 Minutes" from *Atlantis*, where they do this to Sheppard intentionally (he's dying, and it means he'll get medical attention immediately in his personal timeline...)

Comment: @user1886419 What you're describing is relativity. The fact that my personal time has slowed (or even stopped) isn't the same as my personal time going backwards.